# What are the advantages of mRNA vaccines?

Tags: coronavirus, vaccination, mrna, immunity

When the mRNA vaccines for COVID-19 are administered, mRNA molecules are introduced into the cells of the subject. The translation of this mRNA determines the productions of antigens, which in turn stimulate the immune response.

Wouldn't it be simpler to have this translation happen *in vitro*, and then inject the antigen into the subject's body? What are the advantages of making the translation happen *in vivo* instead?

Comment: Quick answer - typical protein-based subunit vaccines tend to produce a strong antibody response (humoral immunity), but not a very strong cellular response. By using an mRNA vaccine that produces the viral protein of interest (in this case the SARS-CoV-2 spike protein) in cells, a strong cellular response can be elicited in addition to the humoral response. This allows for the body's full defenses to be used against an infection right away. I don't have time to give an expanded answer right now, but I'll try to later.

Comment: see paragraph here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_vaccine#:~:text=The%20benefit%20of%20using%20mRNA,COVID%2D19%20in%202%20days.